# SQL Server 2005 : ALTER COLUMN AUTO_INCREMENT and set started ID of AUTO_INCREMENT

Tags: sql-server

I just search and tried for 2 hours, but I still can't solve this

I want to migrate data from another database to my database. I created a  table `tbl_animal` and inserted some values:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_animal
(
    id INT NOT NULL, 
    name VARCHAR (150) NOT NULL
) ;

INSERT INTO tbl_animal (id, name) VALUES (111, 'dog');
INSERT INTO tbl_animal (id, name) VALUES (222, 'bird');
```

and data will be like this

```
______________
id    |   name|
--------------
111   |   dog |
222   |  bird |
--------------
```

Then I want to set `ID` to `AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY` and `SET AUTO_INCREMENT` to start from 223

So if I run

```
INSERT INTO tbl_animal (name) VALUES ('fish')
```

data will be like this

```
______________
id    |   name|
--------------
111   |   dog |
222   |  bird |
223   |  fish |
--------------
```

I try so many solutions, but still can't. The last query that I have tried is

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_animal 
    ALTER COLUMN id int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY;
```

above query throw error code (156):

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IDENTITY'

Thanks for help me

Comment: I'm reading that you are having a problem, but I can't see what that problem is exactly. Can you clarify further? What do you expect the next auto-generated ID to be? `333`? Something else?

Comment: i edited that. thats is typo. i need 223 (222 +1) not 333

Comment: @marc_s thanks for edit my question. i got the point why you edit my question. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding identity to an existing column is not possible. All is not lost however. If you can create the table again you can do this kind of thing pretty easily. Something like this.

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_animal
(
    id INT identity(1, 1) NOT NULL, 
    name VARCHAR (150) NOT NULL
) ;

set identity_insert tbl_animal on 
INSERT INTO tbl_animal (id, name) VALUES (111, 'dog');
INSERT INTO tbl_animal (id, name) VALUES (222, 'bird');
set identity_insert tbl_animal off

dbcc CHECKIDENT('tbl_animal', RESEED, 222) --you really do want 222 here so the next inserted identity will be 223

INSERT INTO tbl_animal (name) VALUES ('fish')

select * from tbl_animal
```

If however you cannot recreate the table this is quite a bit more complicated. If that is the case let me know and I can help you.

Comment: i can recreate table. and this query WORK LIKE CHARM. i just know if we can add identity. because i never do that since now.  thanks man

Comment: If this works for your situation you should consider marking this as the answer so that others will know it worked.